# RLE compression algorithm

Tags: python, compression

I'm trying to run this simple RLE [Run Length Encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Run-length_encoding) compression algorithm. What are my options to return a result?

```
def decode(text_decode):
    decoded_text = ""
    length = len(text_decode)
    if length == 0:
        decoded_text = ""
    elif length == 1:
        decoded_text = text_decode
    else:
        i = 1
        while i < length:
            next_block =""
            for j in range(0, int(text_decode[i])):
                next_block += text_decode[i - 1]
            decoded_text += next_block
            i += 2
    return decoded_text
```

Comment: could you clarify what you mean by that?

Comment: Please describe how the compressed data is stored in `text_decode` (or [edit] your question and add the code that does this).

Answer (score 1):

You haven't described the format of the compressed text adequately—so I guessed by looking at your code and comparing it to related implementations I found searching the web.

Here's a pair of functions that seem to work together:

```
def encode(input_string):
    """ Simple run-length encoder.

    Modified version of code at http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Run-length_encoding#Python
    """
    count = 1
    prev = ''
    lst = []
    for character in input_string:
        if character != prev:
            if prev:
                entry = (prev,count)
                lst.append(entry)
            count = 1
            prev = character
        else:
            count += 1
    else:
        entry = (character,count)
        lst.append(entry)
    return ''.join(chr(cnt)+ch for (ch, cnt) in lst)

def decode(encoded_text):
    """ Simple run-length decoder. """
    chars = []
    a = iter(encoded_text)
    for (cnt, ch) in zip(a, a):
        chars.append(ch * ord(cnt))
    return ''.join(chars)

word = "aaaaahhhhhhmmmmmmmuiiiiiiiaaaaaa"
rle_text = encode(word)
print(len(word))  # -> 32
print(len(rle_text)) # -> 12
print(decode(rle_text))  # -> "aaaaahhhhhhmmmmmmmuiiiiiiiaaaaaa"
```

Answer (score 0):

Like this you can apply your algorithm and run it.
You can also choose the texte that you want to "convert"

```
texte = raw_input("Your text to compress: ")
text_rle = decoded(texte)
print(text_rle)
```